# Which implementation class of set is used by JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, collections

I am using hibernate.

I have one to many relationship.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "enrollmentSetupCategory", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    private Set<EnrollmentSetupCategoryLevel> enrollmentSetupCategoryLevels;
```

My question is which implementation of set I used internally here? If I extend the comparable interface do the object returned will be sorted? 
Or do I have to Sort myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll use the Hibernate's own imlementation of `Set` - `org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet` http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/collection/PersistentSet.html
This class doesn't implement `Comparable` inteface, so you should sort it by yourself or cast it to some sortable implementation of set (e.g `TreeSet`).

Comment: Casting PersistentSet to TreeSet will throw a ClassCastException

Comment: I was just wondering why I don't get deterministic results in a test, while accessing the latest element in a set (I thought it is a TreeSet). Turns out that it is PersistentSet, of course not caring about order. Thank you for the explanation here.

Answer (score 5):

Hibernate Supports sorted collection mapping, you can specify your comparator to do the sorting for you.

From the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-sorted)

> Hibernate supports collections implementing java.util.SortedMap and
>   java.util.SortedSet. You must specify a comparator in the mapping
>   file:
>
> ```
> <set name="aliases" 
>             table="person_aliases" 
>             sort="natural">
>     <key column="person"/>
>     <element column="name" type="string"/>
> </set>
>
> <map name="holidays" sort="my.custom.HolidayComparator">
>     <key column="year_id"/>
>     <map-key column="hol_name" type="string"/>
>     <element column="hol_date" type="date"/>
> </map>
> ```
>
> Allowed values of the sort attribute are unsorted, natural and the
>   name of a class implementing java.util.Comparator.
>
> Sorted collections actually behave like `java.util.TreeSet` or
>   `java.util.TreeMap`.

Edit Annotation From [Docs](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.2/html-single/Hibernate_Annotations_Reference_Guide/index.html), check

> 3.4.6. Collection related annotations

```
 @Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator = TicketComparator.class)
```

Comment: Thanks for response. This is like i am telling hibernate look this comparator that you have to use for sorting. One doubt if i make my class comparable, does it internally understand ok i am comparable class i have to do sorting in the specified order?

Comment: If you look at the hibernate docs, Comparable isnt an option, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/SortType.html

Comment: What's the best way in this case to access the first or last element? I still have the property defined as Set, should I still push it to a new TreeSet(myOriginalSet) to get easy access? In this case I don't have any benefit, as I use natural order and after creating the new TreeSet it is anyways sorted.